# How to set an identified regex term into a string?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to identify 2 types of phrases within a few lines of text, dayday/monthmonth (for example: 29/1) and dayday/monthmonth/yearyearyearyear (29/1/2022)
I already came up with Matchers to match my pattern:

```
Matcher matcherWithYear = pattern.matches((\\d\\d)\\/(\\d\\d)\\/(\\d\\d\\d\\d)");
Matcher matcherNoYear = pattern.matches("(\\d\\d)\\/(\\d\\d)");
```

However, I don't know how to turn the identified phrases into a String.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex quite a bit.  Here is what you're looking for:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}(/\\d{4})?\\b");
String text = "blahblahblabhlah 29/1 asdasd asdasd 29/1/2022";
    
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Except that will find any `nn/nn/nnnn` regardless of what's around it, for example, in the input `323412342/23/23423123423` it will extract `42/23/2342`.   This technically works, but is subject to false hits in mis-behaving input.

Comment: Updated to check for word boundaries

Comment: I don't need to worry about the user putting in invalid dates as I would run these numbers through a date validator. So matcher.group() would take the identified phrase and place it in a string?